# Windows 7 Explorer tree view expand

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When type in the path in address bar (1), or navigate through main panel (3) to the sub-folder, tree view panel (2) won't expand to same sub-folder.

This feature was in Windows XP. Is there any way to enable this feature in Windows 7 Explorer as well?

[image]

Comment: If you find out how please post it, this drives me nuts. I started using Explorer++ or Q-Dir as a replacement because of this. Also when you use the arrow keys in pane 2 to go up or down the directory list, it does not display what is in the highlighted folder unless you press enter, stupid imho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the `Tools` menu and then `Folder Options`.

(I know you do, but in case others don't have the menu, just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>)

Then simply click on `Automatically expand to current folder`.

[image]